# function closure show up variable of outer function

Tags: javascript, counter

Hello I am experimenting with closure, but could not figure it out how to print out "10 likes" before clicking on the image? Is there anyone who can give me some help me with this?

```js
var clickCount = (function() {
 var clickCounter = 10; //start from 10 likes
 return function() {
  var amountOfLikes = document.getElementById("counter");
  amountOfLikes.innerHTML =  clickCounter + " likes"; //increment the likes
  clickCounter++;
 }
})();
```

```html
  <img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png" id="like_button" alt="like-button" onclick="clickCount()"/><span id="counter"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Never mix markup with javascript
2. Try to handle events at javascript
3. You dont need a closure for this.You can set 10 Likes on the markup and just onclick keep on incrementing the value

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("counter").addEventListener('click', clickCount);
}

function clickCount() {
  var amountOfLikes = document.getElementById("counter");
  var likes = parseInt(amountOfLikes.innerHTML, 0);
  amountOfLikes.innerHTML = likes + 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png" id="like_button" alt="like-button" onclick="clickCount()"/><span id="counter">10 </span> likes
```

Hope this helps